# Resolving "Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric" in SQL for insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to create a SQL table with the following column datatypes.

1. Name : Varchar
2. Grade : Data will have “#” followed by numbers and also can be varchar. Eg : #1, #2, TML
3. Sizes : Can be whole numbers and fractions. Eg: 26/30, 80, 85/69
4. Average : Will be decimal numbers.

I have created table based on the above requirements:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report_Proj](
[Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Grade] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Sizes] [float](10) NOT NULL,   
[Average][decimal](10, 10) NOT NULL
```

But when I insert data into this table I’m getting the error “Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.”

Where could I possibly be going wrong.
Need the above data for reporting purposes and will not have any arithematic calculations in future.

Answer (score 2):

just change the decimal value data type to (10,2)

```
declare  @Report_Proj TABLE (
    [Name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Grade] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Sizes] [float](10) NOT NULL,   
    [Average][decimal](18, 2) NOT NULL)

    insert into @Report_Proj ([Name],[Grade],[Sizes],[Average])values ('ram','#1',26/30,10.2)

    select * from @Report_Proj
```

Comment: Thank U! It's resolved. Have been struggling with it for some time!

Comment: Hi, I have a small issue here, I have observed that the "Sizes" value is "0" and not 26/30 after I run the statement. Is it possible to display 26/30 in the column?

Comment: even if you give float because of '/' divided by symbol it is getting divided..instead of that change that data type to varchar(10) and give value in '26/30' in single quotes

Comment: It has executed now. Thnx a ton!

Comment: How I wish I could. I have not got enough reputation to upvote your answer :( . Will do once I can.